# Click button to copy service result to clipboard

Tags: javascript, angular, clipboard

I am trying to copy a service result to the clipboard in angular 2 using ngx-clipboard. But it's returning an existing data value. I want to click a button which gets a value from a java api and copy that returned value to the clipboard. Is there any way to do this with Angular 2?

```
<a class="dropdown-item" [attr.href]="null" (click)="copyPublicLink()" ngxClipboard [cbContent]="publicLink" i18n>Copy Public Link</a>
```

There is a function `copyPublicLink()` which assign "publicLink" variable value getting from java api, inside observer timer block, for ngx-clipboard

```
public copyPublicLink(){ 
  if(this.currentToolbar.sharePublicLink != "") {     
     this.notificationService.publicLinkCopied(); 
  } 
  else { 
      this.navigationService.action(new   NavigationEvent("COPY_PUBLIC_LINK", "")); 
      setTimeout(() => { this.timerSubscription = Observable.interval(500).subscribe(x => { if (this.currentToolbar.sharePublicLink != "") { this.notificationService.publicLinkCopied(); if (this.timerSubscription != null) this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe(); } }); }, 0) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show us the code that you have tried. Its really hard to debug a problem without code.

Comment: <a class="dropdown-item" [attr.href]="null" (click)="copyPublicLink()"  ngxClipboard [cbContent]="publicLink" i18n>Copy Public Link</a>        
 There is a function "copyPublicLink()" which assign "publicLink" variable value getting from java api, inside observer timer block, for ngx-clipboard.

Comment: Please add the function too to your question by editing it.

Comment: public copyPublicLink(){
    if(this.currentToolbar.sharePublicLink != "") {
      this.notificationService.publicLinkCopied();
    }else {
      this.navigationService.action(new NavigationEvent("COPY_PUBLIC_LINK", ""));
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.timerSubscription = Observable.interval(500).subscribe(x => {
          if (this.currentToolbar.sharePublicLink != "") {
            this.notificationService.publicLinkCopied();
            if (this.timerSubscription != null)
              this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
          }
        });

      }, 0)
    }
  }

Comment: "copyPublicLink()"  function observes variable "this.currentToolbar.sharePublicLink" which is a BehaviorSubject variable. if currentToolbar.sharePublicLink has a value, i copy it to clipboard else i wait java api result, api called an other component with "this.navigationService.action(new NavigationEvent("COPY_PUBLIC_LINK", ""))" and currentToolbar.sharePublicLink value changes at result. but some time passes during process, so clipboard copy not succeed at second one.

Answer (score 0):

em,this is the function in Jquery

```
function copy(){
  var e = $(selector) // input
  e.select();
  docuemnt.execCommand("Copy");//execute Copy
}
```

Comment: hi @lee, it copy the selected text but my stuation reuires asyn data coming from api